# Formal proof of convergence of slope of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to find $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$\forall m\geq n\quad \lvert \frac{F_m}{F_{m-1}} - \phi \rvert < \frac{1}{100}$$ where $F_n$ is the n-th term of the Fibonacci sequence and $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio. I know and have proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}} = \phi$ using Binet's formula, however this looks like a formal limit. I would have to express $\lvert \frac{F_m}{F_{m-1}} - \phi \rvert < f(m)$  so that I could find $m$ for $f(m) = \frac{1}{100}$.

I have managed to express $\frac{F_m}{F_{m-1}}$ as $\frac{1}{2} \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n+1} - (1-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n} - (1-\sqrt{5})^{n}}$ using Binet's formula, however this didn't bring me far.

Through numerical calculations I have found that :
\begin{array}{c|c}
 m & \frac{F_m}{F_{m-1}} \\\hline
 1  & 1    \\\hline
 2  & 2  \\\hline
 3  & 1.5    \\\hline
 4  & 1.66667 \\\hline
 5  & 1.6 \\\hline
 6  & 1.6250 \\\hline
 7  & 1.6154 \\\hline
 8  & 1.6190 \\\hline
 9  & 1.6176 \\\hline
 10  & 1.6182
\end{array}

However, I couldn't find a proof for this fact. So my question, is there any way to do a formal proof of the convergence of the slope of the Fibonacci sequence ?

Comment: You can also ask your TAs on ETH discord, they are always happy to help :D

Comment: I know, but I thought it would be nice to make such hints available to the public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you look [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ratio_of_Consecutive_Fibonacci_Numbers)

$$\frac {F_{n + 1} } {F_n}= \phi + \dfrac {\sqrt 5} {\alpha^n - 1}\quad \text{where} \qquad \alpha=\dfrac {\phi} {\hat \phi}=\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 5} {1 - \sqrt 5}$$ So, looking for $n$ such that
$$\left|\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\phi \right|\leq \epsilon \implies \left|\alpha^n-1\right| \geq \frac{\sqrt 5}\epsilon $$ It looks simple (taka care that $\alpha <0$).

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\epsilon}$

Comment: @BrockenDuck. This is a superb typo ! Sorry for that ! Cheers  :-(